# Returning function values based on argument?

Tags: python

I am having this problem in the below program flow where func1 needs list3,list4 but I dont want to return them from func2 because it affects the sanctity of func2,is there a way we can return based on some conditions?global is one way but that wont work for me because I will calling these functions with different values,lists being returned depends on the operations performed on value..what other options I have?

```
def func3 (value):
    list3=[]
    list4=[]
    #do some operations based on value
    return list3,list4

def func2 (value,flag):
    list1=[]
    list2=[]
    value=10
    #do some operations based on value
    if flag:
        (list3,list4)=func3(value)
    return list1,list2

def func1() :
    value =20
    (list1,list2)= func2(value,1)
    #func1 needs list3 and list4

def main():
    func1()

if __name__ == '__main__':
    main()
```

Comment: What do you mean by *sanctity* here? I don't really get what your problem is. Does `func3()` mutate the list? If not, then just do it again (or do it once and let `func2` take them as optional parameters if the computation is taxing). If it does, consider making it not do so - by making a copy if needs be.

Comment: @Lattyware - Well,the purpose of func2 will be destroyed..I need to call func2 sometimes without the necessity to call func3 inside it in which case I cant return list3,list 4

Comment: Then why not call `func3()` in `func1()`?

Comment: @user1927233: But you're already calling `func3` instead `func2`, even without the necessity to return its return values. Your question makes very little sense; give us a stripped-down version of the actual thing you're trying to do, rather than showing us random snippets of how you're trying to do it.

Comment: Also, with regards for your edit, if you have a flag, use `True` or `False`, over `1`/`0` - it's far more readable.

Comment: @Lattyware - based on some operations in func2,func3 need to be called from func2 sometimes

Comment: Why does that matter? Just because you called it in one place doesn't stop you from calling it in another.

Comment: Is there some _other_ code that calls `func2(something, 0)`, and expects to get back 2 lists instead of 4? If so, you have two different APIs—one returns 2 lists, one returns 4—and that should be written as two functions that both call the same internal function (similar to the "wrapper function" example in my answer). However, it's _possible_ to have a single function that returns 2 `list`s when called with `flag=0`, 4 `list`s otherwise; there's nothing stopping you from doing that, it'll just be harder to read later.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I'm not sure what you mean by "I dont want to return them from func2 because it affects the sanctity of func2", but I'm assuming you mean that `func` has an obvious API, and this would break that API.

Nevertheless, if you want a caller to be able to use those values from of `func2`, you have to pass them out *some* way. Here are some alternatives:

```
# Internal function used by func2 and func1
def func2_(value):
    list1=[]
    list2=[]
    value=10
    #do some operations based on value
    (list3,list4)=func3(value)
    return list1, list2, list3, list4

# Real func2 with the desired public API
def func2(value):
    list1, list2, _, _ = func2_(value)
    return list1, list2

def func1() :
    value =20
    (list1,list2,list3,list4)= func2_(value)
    #func1 _has_ list3 and list4
```

If the issue is that `func2` sometimes calls `func3`, and sometimes doesn't, but `func1` always needs to have `list3` and `list4` no matter what… then you have to figure out what values `func1` *should* get if `func3` is never called, and then just return that value. Obvious choices are `[]`, `None`, or a default value passed in by the caller:

```
def func2():
    list1=[]
    list2=[]
    value=10
    if somePredicate():
        (list3,list4)=func3(value)
        return list1, list2, list3, list4
    else:
        return list1, list2, None, None
```

If you're sure that `func2` should always be calling `func3` when it's called by `func1`, even if there are *other* cases where it may not be, you want the wrapper-function solution above.

Or, you could even just not return the values—there's no rule that says your return value always has to have the same number of components. This will almost certainly cause readability problems for you in the future, but it's perfectly legal:

```
def func2():
    list1=[]
    list2=[]
    value=10
    if somePredicate():
        (list3,list4)=func3(value)
        return list1, list2, list3, list4
    else:
        return list1, list2
```

If the calling functions know when to expect 2 `list`s vs. 4, again, you've got two different functions, so you want the wrapper. But if it's not predictable, they can handle it dynamically:

```
lists = function2(value)
if len(lists) == 4:
    list1, list2, list3, list4 = lists
    # do stuff will all 4 lists
else:
    list1, list2 = lists
    # do stuff with just 2 lists—or, if you needed the others, complain
```

Or, if you've got a set of data and a set of operations that cohesively fit together, that might be a job for an object:

```
class Class1(object):
    def __init__(self):
        self.list1, self.list2, self.list3, self.list4 = [], [], [], []
    def func3 (value):
        self.list3=[]
        self.list4=[]
        #do some operations based on value (that presumably modify list3/list4)
    def func2(self, value):
        self.list1=[]
        self.list2=[]
        #do some operations based on value (that presumably modify list1/list2)
        self.func3(value) # this sets self.list3 and self.list4
    def func1(self):
        value =20
        self.func2(value)
        #func1 now has access to the same self.list3 and self.list4 as func2
```

Answer (score 1):

If you want it you need to return it. The only other option would be a global which would be even uglier.

You can obviously return different values (even tuples of different sizes or different types altogether) depending on some condition. Use `if` for this. However, doing so is usually rather ugly since it often requires additional code when calling the function. For example, `x, y = foo()` would fail with an exception if `foo()` returned something that is not a collection of two elements.

Comment: I wouldn't say it's ugly - it depends on how it will be used. If the caller will loop over the tuple, then it wouldn't be a problem at all.

Comment: True, but then you most likely won't `return x, y` but `return some_collection`. In the `return x, y` case chances are good that the caller wants to be able to use an unpacking assignment.

Comment: Indeed, but I thought I'd mention just in case.

Answer (score 1):

So if I understand you correctly, you want func_1 to have access to list1, list2, list3, and list4, and since you see that you've already called func_3 inside, you want to utilize that call in the future?

One easy way to do this, is to simply define a helper function, as stated above, or, give func_2 2 variables such as:

```
def func_2(value, lists_3_4=false):
     list1=[]
     list2=[]
     value=10
     #do some operations based on value
     (list3,list4)=func3(value)
     if lists_3_4:
     return list1, list2, list3, list4 
     return list1,list2
```

But again, this might be breaking whatever you're defining as sanctity.

abarnert's solution is probably the cleanest utilizing helper functions in my opinion.